# DAG Run Logs are not time sensitive

Tags: airflow

Hi all and thanks for reading my question.

I've noticed after some weeks of deploying and changing DAGs that the logs are only reflecting the structure of the latest design.

For example, I have a DAG with 3 sequential operators. That DAG has run 10 times with a mix of success and failure. Before the 11th run, I re-deployed the DAG again with 2 sequential operators (removing 1 operator).

Now, the DAG is showing all the logs (11 runs) based on the latest design (2 operators) and does not change to the 3-operator view when I look at older logs.

Is there a way to "fix" this?

Thanks and regards,
Rama

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the structure of the DAG in the UI.
When you change the structure (add or remove new tasks) it is going to apply the structural changes in the UI through the previous runs.
If you want to keep the history of the structure the best way would be to create a new dag or rename the dag:

```
with DAG(
    dag_id='dag_name_1.0', -- change to dag_name_1.1
    schedule_interval="0 2 * * *",
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
    default_args=default_args,
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup=False,
    doc_md=__doc__
    ) as dag:
```

You can access the older logs, just not through the ui. Check the **base_log_folder** in you airflow config file and you are going to be able to find the log files in that address.

Comment: Thanks Peter - I suspected as much!